# How to get a live exchange rate data and apply it to an Android App?

Tags: android

How to get a live exchange rate data and apply it to an Android App?
Currently creating a currency exchange as my project.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide info on what part you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.  I would say the best thing for you to do is to read up on:

- Currency rate APIs, [such as Xurrency.com](http://xurrency.com/api)
- [Android Development](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

If there's a specific problem you're running into with your project, I'm sure the folks here on SO would love to hear more details about your problem in order to help.

Best,

-aj

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you have to make your application connect to some kind of webservice to retrieve the exchange rate data needed.

- http://www.anddev.org/calling_a_web_service_from_android-t348.html has some indications.
- I suggest you read the book from M. Murphy ( Begginning Android ). Chap 22 says :

> Android does not have built-in SOAP or XML-RPC client APIs. However, it does have the Apache
>   HttpComponents library baked in. You can either layer a SOAP/XML-RPC layer atop this library, or
>   use it “straight” for accessing REST-style Web services. For the purposes of this book, “RESTstyle
>   Web services” is defined as simple HTTP requests for ordinary URLs over the full range of
>   HTTP verbs, with formatted payloads (XML, JSON, etc.) as responses.